# Mikro-ORM - File attachments

Tags: typescript, nestjs, database-schema, mikro-orm

I'm trying to find a clever-ish solution for attaching files to multiple entities. Let's say I have entities Book, Author and Store. Each of these can have multiple attachments by referencing an entity FileAttachment. Now I know I could have a separate file attachment array on each of those 3 entities all referencing a different column on a FileAttachment entity. But I wonder if it is possible to have a BaseEntity class that is the parent for Book, Author and Store that has one variable that depending on the child class references a different column on the FileAttachment entity. So something like this:

```
class BaseEntity{
  files: FileAttachment[]
}

class Book : BaseEntity{
// Some other properties here
}

class FileAttachment{
  refToBook: Book
  refToAuthor: Author
  refToStore: Store
}
```

It would be even better if the FileAttachment could look like this:

```
class FileAttachment{
  usedBy: BaseEntity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this using table inheritance. It even allows me to use the "usedBy" improvement